Why aren't rune enabled transparently with the old syntax, and when not to use them?
Svelte 5 introduce runes, and recommends now to write:
let foo = $state(42);

instead of the elegant
let foo = 42;

I can understand why it makes sense in React… but since svelte is a compiler, why can't it automatically compile let foo = 42; into its rune equivalent? I guess that because sometimes one might NOT want to assign something via a rune… but it which case would a standard let be better than a "rune let"?

There are multiple reasons:

The added reactivity has a certain amount of overhead (it creates a signal internally).
For objects, it wraps the object in a Proxy, which can also cause certain issues and will impact performance since every access goes though said proxy.
It is less explicit without $state. Svelte 5 moves away from all the "magic".
See this point in the tenets:

Magical, not magic
There's a subtle line between something feeling magical, and something feeling like magic. We want Svelte to feel magical — we want you to feel like a wizard when you're writing Svelte code. Historically I think Svelte went too far into magic territory, where it's not 100% clear why things work a certain way, and that's something that we're rectifying with Svelte 5.




Thanks, but then is there a good rule of thumb on when to use a rune or not? I used precisely svelte to avoid thinking about any efficiency-related choice, thinking that the compiler would pick the best choice for me… seems like it's not :-\

If you need reactivity, use runes. If you don't need reactivity, use plain old JS without runes.

I too find it annoying having to write $state( ... ) to create a reactive variable. When Vue introduced this similar change some years ago, that was one of the reasons I changed to Svelte, and now Svelte does it too xD IMO, it would be better to change the let keyword to reactive (or something like that) for reactive variables. I think that's a shame, though. Since Svelte already requires a compiler, why not go all the way and create something optimal, instead of letting existing limitations stand in your way?

@PeppeL-G: Because you have to overhaul or completely rewrite all the existing tooling around JS/TS if you go outside the bounds of the language. It would have its advantages if Svelte had its own language but it would break everything in the ecosystem/tools space.
